# LESS @import not bringing over variables and mixins when used in SailsJS (through GruntJS)

Tags: node.js, gruntjs, less, sails.js

I have a project that I've been building on top of nodejs, and today I've decided to move to the sailsjs framework before this project gets too complicated. I've encountered a few issues.

While porting over my LESS files, I found that all of my assets were failing to load, and was getting 404's in my console. I managed to narrow the problem down to my LESS files.

What was happening was, where I was using @import to bring in files that contains mixins and variables, none of those were actually being brought over. They were undefined, and this seemed to be making everything fail. All that said, this never actually threw compiler errors in --verbose mode. It all just failed silently.

To ensure that this was the problem, I ran a little test:

test1.less:

```
@myvar: #f00;
```

test2.less:

```
@import 'test2.less';

body {
    background-color:@myvar;
}
```

These are the only files present in my styles/ folder. With the code above, I encounter the problem. If I comment out the

```
//background-color:@myvar;
```

everything works fine again.

I've been looking around for people having the same problem, but I haven't found anything. I'm at a bit of a loss, and feel like I've missed something very trivial.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

With grunt you need to make the import on every file.

What you do is good but in your test you should import test1.less and not test2.less

Comment: ....oh god how did I not notice that I did that. Now I'm just baffled because that mistake was limited to the test, and fixing it made the test actually work... Looks like I'm back to the drawing board for what my original problem is. Thanks, though!

Comment: I just reread your response and noted the first part - that was *definitely* my original mistake, so thank you very much!